# Почему вторая итерация для запроса к серверу ошибочна?

Tags: c++, http, сокет

```
while(1){
        const char sendBuff[1000] = "GET /\nHOST: google.com\n\n\0";
        char recvBuff[1000]{0};

        int sended = SSL_write(ssl, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)+1);


        int received = 0;
        while((received = SSL_read(ssl, recvBuff, 1000)) > 0)
            cout << recvBuff;

        cout << "sended: " << sended << ", received: " << received << endl;

        Sleep(5000);
}
```

Цикл выпоняется 1 раз, я получаю html-тело страницы. На вторую итерацию сервер не отправляет мне ничего (received == 0). Подскажите пожалуйста, почему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо передавать `\0`, уберите `+1` у `strlen`.

Возможно надо добавить Connection: Keep-Alive.

(Также используйте `\r\n` и добавьте версию хттп в строку запроса)

Comment: Отправляю такой запрос: GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: google.com\nConnection: keep-alive\nKeep-Alive: 300\r\n\0   Все равно не хочет работать, убрать +1 у strlen